# React - How to remove a button in Ant Design Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, ant-design-pro

I installed the Ant Design framework for my React project but how can I not remove the button from the name "**cancle**"

I'll leave a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/d4qxs?file=/index.js) and [documentation](https://ant.design/components/modal/)

Comment: You want to remove the styles from the cancel button or to remove the cancel button altoghether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the docs use `footer` props for custom footer button bar:

```
<Modal
      visible={visible}
      title="Title"
      onOk={this.handleOk}
      onCancel={this.handleCancel}
      footer={[
        <Button
          key="submit"
          type="primary"
          loading={loading}
          onClick={this.handleOk}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      ]}
    >
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
      <p>Some contents...</p>
    </Modal>
```

here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4122-forked-0gjeu?file=/index.js)